# AttributeError: 'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, classification, pypdf

I tried extracting the uploaded pdf file, how to extract the file, the problem is that I've tried using various functions to extract and still can't. anyone i beg for your help.
why pdfFileRaeder doesn't find the attribute decode, or how to add the attribute decode on pdfFileReader. when i try to make the variable to list i got some error the list has no attribute decode. please somebody help me why this code doesn't working

this is my code

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        file = (f, 'rb')
        #f.save(f.filename)
        #data = f.save(f.filename)
        pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        import nltk
        nltk.download('punkt')
        from tika import parser
        from nltk import tokenize
        pdfreader = parser.from_file(pdfreader)
        tokenize.sent_tokenize(pdfreader['content'])
        sentence = tokenize.sent_tokenize(pdfreader['content'])
        from pandas import DataFrame
        df1 = DataFrame(sentence, columns=['isi1'])
        vect = count_vect.transform(['isi1']).toarray()
        df1['label1'] = text_clf.predict(df1['isi1'])
        df1.append(['label1'])
        hasil = (df1.isi1[df1['label1'] == 'positif'])
        len(hasil)
        hasil_list = hasil.values.tolist()
        stringList = ' '.join([str(item) for item in hasil_list])
        hasil_ringkas = stringList

    return render_template('result.html', ringkasan = hasil_ringkas)
```

This is stack frame error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\app.py", line 78, in summarize
pdfreader = parser.from_file(pdfreader)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\tika\parser.py", line 40, in from_file
output = parse1(service, filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers, config_path=config_path, requestOptions=requestOptions)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 326, in parse1
path, file_type = getRemoteFile(urlOrPath, TikaFilesPath)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 730, in getRemoteFile
urlp = urlparse(urlOrPath)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 367, in urlparse
url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 123, in _coerce_args
return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 107, in _decode_args
return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 107, in <genexpr>
return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Please post the stack frame. It tells us which line has the error.

Comment: Try `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(*file)` to expand the arguments properly.

Comment: @KlausD. when i try i get "TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 2412 were given"

Comment: @tdelaney done, i was editing the post and i was add the error line

Comment: Have you tried `pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(f,'rb'))`?

Comment: @Noki I was tried it, but I got error like this "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"

Comment: which is the type of variable f¿? @NoviliaAnggraini

Comment: @Noki The type of variable is Object.

Comment: @Noki I tried that again. I got this error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage"

Comment: Then it means you need to open the tmp filestorage. Do you have a linux OS? `pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('/tmp/' + f.filename,'rb'))`

Comment: @Noki when I tried it. It said "No such file temporary". I don't have a linux OS

Comment: Basically, the problem is that you need to open the file before calling the PdfFileReader. If you use the `open()` python function, you need the file path. My linux approach works, but in windows I don't really know which is the tmp equivalent

Comment: I have tried searching tmp files on windows, and i find it, it's Temp in my local. but when I check into that folder there are no files that have been uploaded before.

Comment: ```data = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('C:/Users/Novilia/AppData/Local/Temp/' + f.filename, 'rb')) ```

Comment: @Noki, how to save uploaded files to temp files?